# xml transform using xlts, order by alphabet

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have this <del>XSD</del> XML (happens to be a WSDL) file:

```
<definitions targetNamespace="http://soft.com/" name="LoggingWebService" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.config.softid.softcomputer.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://soft.com/" schemaLocation="my.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="log">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:log"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getLogs">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getLogs"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getLogsResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getLogsResponse"/>
  </message>
</definitions>
```

I want transform this file using `javax.transformation` to another file, where `messages` will be ordered by alphabet (using string in 'name').

```
<definitions targetNamespace="http://soft.com/" name="LoggingWebService" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.config.softid.softcomputer.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://soft.com/" schemaLocation="my.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="getLogs">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getLogs"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getLogsResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getLogsResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="log">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:log"/>
  </message>
</definitions>
```

What XSLT file I need for this? Help me plz

Comment: See xsl:sort http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp

Comment: This is not an XSD file; it is a WSDL; your question has nothing to do with either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XSLT transform will do what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        version="1.0" >

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 

    <xsl:template match="/wsdl:definitions" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="wsdl:types" />
            <xsl:for-each select="wsdl:message" >
                <xsl:sort select="@name" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.config.softid.softcomputer.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
   <types>
      <xsd:schema>
         <xsd:import namespace="http://soft.com/" schemaLocation="my.xsd"/>
      </xsd:schema>
   </types>
   <message name="getLogs">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:getLogs"/>
   </message>
   <message name="getLogsResponse">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:getLogsResponse"/>
   </message>
   <message name="log">
      <part name="parameters" element="tns:log"/>
   </message>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Can you look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754867/xml-transform-using-xlts-order-by-alphabet-in-inner-node